# Git diff with three-dots symmetric notation with dot slash working tree

Tags: git

How can I use the `...` syntax with the `./` working tree syntax.

The `...` syntax internally does a `git merge-base master HEAD`, for example:

```
git diff master...HEAD
```

And the `./` syntax compares against the working tree, for example:

```
git diff master:./
```

Is it possible to use `...` and `./` together? I've tried this:

```
git diff master..../
```

But it is not working.

**UPDATE:**

Maybe it is not possible because `git merge-base master ./` is not supported, though I would expect that internally it does a `git merge-base master HEAD`.

Answer (score 2):

(Worth mentioning: this special merge-base behavior is specific to `git diff`.)

It's not possible because neither the index nor the work-tree are a commit.  The merge-base calculation is done with two commits as input.

More precisely, `git diff A...B` parses `A...B` using the same code as `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/master...master
80b88a51c112215a56f0e73dab804c4e17248f3b
3afc4b6899bfb87ca3e397c62463fc9cdd070fb6
^3afc4b6899bfb87ca3e397c62463fc9cdd070fb6
```

The output from the above `git rev-parse`, in simple cases like the above, is three hash IDs: that of the right hand side, that of the merge base, and—negated—that of the left hand side.  (If there are multiple merge bases, all of them come between the RHS and the negated LHS.)

Internally within `git diff`, these same commit hash IDs show up in an array, in the same order (subscript zero representing the non-negated RHS).  The diff code notices that there are multiple positive references and one final negated reference, and runs `git diff` on two commit hash IDs: one of the merge bases from the middle, and the non-negated hash ID at subscript zero.

Since neither the index nor the work-tree have a commit ID, `git diff` cannot feed them to the revision parsing code.  That means this same chunk of code cannot return an array with three-or-more elements with the last one marked "negated".

Git *could*, but does not, have entirely different code to handle this.  But since it's just a convenient syntax, you can do it yourself:

```
git diff $(git merge-base master HEAD)
```

to compare the merge base of `master` and `HEAD` (or one randomly chosen merge base, in the case of multiple bases) to the current work-tree, or add `--cached` to compare that same merge base to the index.

Comment: It make sense. Does the `$(command)` is a bash/Unix feature? It seems that is not supported on Windows command line.

Comment: Yes, `$(...)` is POSIX shell (bash, sh, others). I understand PowerShell has something even fancier than this, that can do everything that sh/bash can do.